# deserialize rest api xml response c#

Tags: c#, rest

I have a task to make a call to REST API which gives an XML output. The xml output should be deserialized into a .NET class which can be queried later. I am not sure where I am doing  wrong, but the code gives an error. On debugging the code, I figured out the issue is when trying to deserialize the response stream it gives an error saying 'responsestream.Length threw an exception of type System.NotSupportedException'. Please help me to figure out this issue. 
Below is my sample code.

```
WebRequest request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(apiurl);
request.Method = "GET";
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ResponseClass>));
    var apiresponse = (List<ResponseClass>)serializer.Deserialize(responsestream);
}
```

Comment: have you tried updating the Rest API's service reference in you project?  The type may have changed.

Comment: I did, but still it gives the same issue. I might be handling the response stream in a wrong way which might be the cause.

Comment: maybe check the reference, not sure if it would matter, but it could be using IEnumerable<ResponseClass> rather than List<ResponseClass>

Comment: You are going to have to read the entire response then deserialize it,  the stream returned by `GetResponseStream` does not support the `Length` property which the deserializer uses.